# How do I Insert commas into a number string being imported?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to insert commas and dollar sign into string of numbers that represent currency.  Is this best done with the website code or from the sqlcmd and what would that look like?

Webpage:

```
<div id='week'> 
    <?php
        echo "<table>\n\n";

        $f = fopen("week.csv", "r");
        while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false) {
                echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($line as $cell) {
                        echo "<td>Past Week:   $" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        fclose($f);
        echo "\n</table>";
    ?>
</div>
```

CSS File:

```
body {
    background-position:center;
    background-image: url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#title {
margin-top:300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center ;
    Font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
}

#week td {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center ;
    Font-family: Arial;
    color: red;
}

 #week {
    border-color: white;
    height:50px;
    width:350;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top:10px;
```

Batch File:

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -U username -P password -d money -Q "declare @today datetime = '2014-5-21' set nocount on; select [Week Total] = (convert(varchar, convert(decimal(18, 2), sum([TotalJackpotAmount])), 3)) from [Accounting].[dbo].[HandPay] where [AccountingDate] <= @today and [AccountingDate] > dateadd(week, -1, @today);" -o \\location\to\write\file\Week.csv -h -1 -s ","
```

If the CSS is needed I can upload that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format)

```
foreach ($line as $cell) {
                        echo "<td>Past Week:   $" . number_format(htmlspecialchars($cell)) . "</td>";
                }
```